# Extract blob characteristics

Tags: python, opencv

In OpenCV I am aware that you can set parameters such as circularity, convexity and inertia as filters for the blobs which are returned.

Is there a way to extract these as outputs? We are looking for a mechanism to 'score' resulting blobs.

Answer (score 0):

The SIFT algorithm performs a multiscale analysis with a DOG kernel (Difference Of Gaussian) which presents maximos in BLOBS structures. This algorithm not only finds the key points (coordinates) where these structures are found but also encloses each point with a circle whose radius is proportional to the scale in which it was found.

http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html